# poblema agregando repositorio en ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Intento agregar un repositorio en mi ubuntu 16.04 y recibo este mensaje de error.

> jaime@jaime-HP:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 95, in 
>       sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py",
>   line 114, in **init**
>       self.reload_sourceslist()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py",
>   line 607, in reload_sourceslist
>       self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 89, in
>   get_sources
>       (self.id, self.codename)) aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a
>   distribution template for neon/xenial

¿Como podria solucionarlo?

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque este tema debería tratarse en los foros de soporte de ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ejecuta `$ gksudo gedit /etc/lsb-release`

Después edita el archivo que abre poniendo esto:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
```

Tienes que ingresar la version de Ubuntu que estés utilizando, en mi caso es xenial 16.04.3 y despues haces un :
`sudo apt-get update` y por ultimo ejecutas tu comando `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`

Comment: Muchas gracias J.Gama, realmente me funció muy bien y sin problemas. Quiero hacerte una pregunta, es que soy nuevo en esto de ubuntu. El valor que tenía mi **/etc/lsb-release** era este: 
**
DISTRIB_ID=neon
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="KDE neon User Edition 5.11"
**
¿Sabes cómo se puedo cambiar?. Gracias

Comment: @JaimeRoman puedes abrir el documento con `sudo gedit /etc/lsb-release` y modificar la información. No te recomiendo que la cambies por datos que no son de tu version.